# Eu não deveria poder votar para reabrir a minha própria pergunta. Ou deveria?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Atualmente eu posso votar para reabrir a minha própria pergunta.

Isso na minha perspectiva é um erro de *design* do `SE`. Os utilizadores não deveriam poder reabrir as suas próprias perguntas.

O motivo é que o utilizador tem todo interesse em reabrir a sua própria pergunta e por ser o autor da pergunta ele tem um *bias* em relação a ela. É mais provável que considere que a sua pergunta não tem nenhum problema.

O autor não deveria poder votar para reabrir a própria pergunta. Ou deveria?

Podemos mudar o comportamento do site para este caso?

Comment: Qual o problema que você está resolvendo se proibir do usuário fazer isso? Em outras palavras, se a pessoa vota pra reabrir a própria pergunta, qual o dano causado?

Comment: Deveria sim. Algumas perguntas que são fechadas podem ser melhoradas. Depois de editar a pergunta, melhorá-la e dar mais informações o AP ficaria sem saída. Da forma atual, o AP vota para reabertura e a comunidade reavalia. Além de que "*`utilizador tem todo interesse em reabrir a sua própria pergunta`*" isso é inválido uma vez que a pergunta precisa ter 5 votos para poder ser reaberta.

Comment: Você não reabre, você só vota para reabrir, quem reabre é outras pessoas, isso vai para a fila de analise.

Comment: @Bacco Eu considero ser apenas uma questao de lógica/principio, nada mais. Eu sei que é preciso aprovacao de outros utilizadores para reabrir a pergunta. MAs acho que eu votar para a reabrir, ter o meu nome na lista de pessoas que votou para reabrir nao faz muito sentido. é uma decisao que cabe a outras pessoas neste caso, nao a mim.

Comment: Se a pessoa pode votar para fechar, não vejo porque não pode votar para reabrir. Não acho que tenha havido qualquer problema porque a pessoa pode votar.

Comment: Tudo certo entao, desculpem pela pergunta inocente

Comment: @BrunoCosta não é crítica, não precisa pedir desculpas. A gente pergunta como um jeito de problematizar a situação e entender melhor o que você pensou. No que a gente confronta a idéia, você acaba deixando mais claro o que pensa, aí tanto você como nós temos mais material para por na balança e avaliar a idéia.

Comment: @BrunoCosta o META é para isto também, tirar duvidas, não fez nada de errado, pelo contrário fez o certo.

Comment: @BrunoCosta és português?

Comment: @JorgeB.Sim sou, porque?

Comment: Bruno o Jorge também é portugues, é que o pessoal estranhou a escrita, mas agora foi esclarecido, estava a escrever como se pronuncia.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O meu teclado neste momento é ingles, o que nao é ideal para escrever portugues. O meu browser no trabalho também nao dá para verificar a ortografia automáticamente, nao sei porque, o que nao ajuda...

Comment: Não há problema, só estávamos tentando entender o texto como *devia puder votar*, mas agora já foi esclarecido e edições para tentar melhorar já foram feitas, seja bem vindo ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não reabre a pergunta, você só vota para reabrir, ou seja isso é só uma solicitação, quem vai avaliar são outras pessoas, se elas acharem a pergunta ainda com problemas ela irá continuar fechada, simples assim.

Você votar para reabrir uma pergunta é só um pedido de solicitação, não é nada grandioso e não afeta em nada, pois quem decide são outros usuários.

**Note** que se uma pergunta foi fechada e alguém edita ela, então ela entra na fila de analise diretamente, sem o autor precisar votar.

Leia mais em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

> Para ter acesso a fila de analise é necessário 3.000 Pontos De Reputação